# Matlab get actual value of 'xTick'

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm using Matlab to plotting data and trying to deal with the ticks/tick labels.

## What I intend to do

Draw a graph with dynamic tick labels so I can find out the timestamp of a specific point on the graph. Thus the timestamp (`xTickLabel`) should only come from the data source.

## What I achieved

Now I can:

Draw a graph with dynamic tick labels, but the labels are not fine enough: those labels are one-second per tick.

Here's the code of plotting:

```
fig = figure;
x = M(:, 1);

% convert the x (time) value from unix time to matlab time
x = (x / 86400 / 1000) + datenum(1970,1,1);
y1 = M(1:end, 2);
y2 = M(1:end, 3);
y3 = M(1:end, 4);

plot(x, y1, x, y2, x, y3);

xlim([x(1), x(end)]);

set(gca, 'XTick', x);
grid on;

datetick('x','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF', 'keeplimits', 'keepticks');
xticklabel_rotate;

hleg1 = legend('x', 'y', 'z');
% zoomAdaptiveDateTicks('on');
```

The code works fine and can plot the graph with every timestamp comes from the source data without enable the `zoomAdaptiveDateTicks('on')`, the original graph is displayed as below:

[image: matlab1]

and if `zoomAdaptiveDateTicks('on')` is enabled, the graph will have dynamic tick labels, but the labels are one-second per tick with regardless of the zoom scale.

[image: matlab2]

## My Question

How can I make the graph with both fine-enough and dynamic tick labels?

I tried to find out the tick label values but no luck, is there any other way to do this?

Thanks,

And for your reference, here's the code of `zoomAdaptiveDateTicks`([link](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15342-zoom-adaptive-date-ticks))

```
 function zoomAdaptiveDateTicks(varargin)
% ZOOMADAPTIVEDATETICKS - Make date ticks adapt to zooming
%
% zoomAdaptiveDateTicks('on')
% Turns on the automatic adaptation of date ticks
% to user zooming for the current figure window
%
% zoomAdaptiveDateTicks('off')
% Turns off the automatic adaptation of date ticks
% to user zooming for the current figure window
% 
% zoomAdaptiveDateTicks('demo')
% Opens a demo figure window to play with


if (nargin>0)
   switch varargin{1}
      case 'demo'
         % Create demo values
         dates = floor(now) - linspace(1169,0,15000)';
         values= randn(15000,1);
         % Show data with date ticks
         figure
         plot(dates,values)
         datetick('x')
         zoomAdaptiveDateTicks('on')
      case 'on'
         % Define a post zoom callback
         set(zoom(gcf),'ActionPostCallback', @adaptiveDateTicks);
      case 'off'
         % Delete the post zoom callback
         set(zoom(gcf),'ActionPostCallback', '');
      otherwise
         figure(gcf)
   end
end


function adaptiveDateTicks(figureHandle,eventObjectHandle)

% Resetting x axis to automatic tick mark generation 
 set(eventObjectHandle.Axes,'XTickMode','auto')

% get and set the tick length
% a = get(eventObjectHandle.Axes, 'XTick');
% minimum = min(a);
% maximum = max(a);

fprintf('minimum :%s, maximum:%s \n', num2str(minimum), num2str(maximum));
% set(eventObjectHandle.Axes, 'XTick'
%set(eventObjectHandle.Axes, 'TickLength', 0.5*(get(eventObjectHandle.Axes, 'TickLength')))

% using automaticallly generate date ticks
datetick(eventObjectHandle.Axes,'x','keeplimits')
```

Please feel free to ask if I didn't explain the question clearly.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/determining-axes-zoom-state. Also note the tiny piece of code in the comments on that page.

Comment: @ss1271 if the link posted by Dev-iL helped you solve the problem, it would be kind of you if you posted a small summary of your solution, because this question/answer could be useful to future visitors in my opinion.

Comment: @Dev-iL Hi, I tried the method inside the comment, it returned the same value as this function `a = get(eventObjectHandle.Axes, 'XTick')` any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with `xticklabel_rotate`, since it freezes the labels. 
So I thought maybe I should do something like this in the callback:

```
   set(gca,'XTickLabelMode','auto');
   xticklabel_rotate;
```

But this didn't work... Then I noticed line 35 in `xticklabel_rotate.m`:

```
% Note : you can not RE-RUN xticklabel_rotate on the same graph.
```

You should try [rotateXLabels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels) instead of `xticklabel_rotate`.

---

As per ss1271's comment, the following code was able to achieve the desired result. The required modification is replacing the duo `zoomAdaptiveDateTicks('on')` & `xticklabel_rotate` with `rotateXLabels(gca, 90)`:

```
close all force; clear variables; clc;

M = [(1:1000)',randn(1000,3)]; ...' //This is just to fix SO formatting

fig = figure(1337);
x = M(:, 1);

% convert the x (time) value from unix time to matlab time
x = (x / 86400 / 1000) + datenum(1970,1,1);
y1 = M(:, 2);
y2 = M(:, 3);
y3 = M(:, 4);

plot(x, y1, x, y2, x, y3);

xlim([x(1), x(end)]);

set(gca, 'XTick', x);
grid on;

datetick('x','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF','keepticks','keeplimits');

rotateXLabels(gca, 90);

hleg1 = legend('x', 'y', 'z');
```

Comment: I'll try your method and report back how it works. Thanks mate :)

Comment: After further experimentation, I am quite convinced that tag rotation and auto-scale of axes is incompatible with one another, unless (possibly) you replot the data in between. In which case it's only seemingly automatic :\ || I'm Sorry I wasn't of much help.

Comment: actually I manage to do it! Maybe I didn't describe my question clearly. pls refer to my answer. thanks anyway, the `rotateXLabels` submission really works